# What software for (1) free dating (not Reddit) (2) Windows 10 computer (3) NOT based on location (4) that shows faces?

Tags: social-networks

I can't afford to pay for online dating. I know Reddit has dating sub-reddits, but I've had no luck!

I have vision problems. I like using my Windows laptop rather than iPhone. I'm 19. I need to see other users' face pictures to make sure they're in my age range.

I live in a Trumpist Republican town in the US, which makes it obvious why I don't want geo-location. I want to date people far outside my area.